# How do I solve this error about Android Studio flutter code?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Originally I can run the flutter code in AS, but suddenly can't.
I didn't modify a code in ffi.dart file...
I wanna run the code using Chrome(Web)

Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
lib/main.dart:1:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ffi' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ffi';
^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:ffi' is imported through these packages:

```
web_entrypoint.dart => package:contact => dart:ffi
```

Detailed import paths for (some of) the these imports:

```
web_entrypoint.dart => package:contact/main.dart => dart:ffi
```

Failed to compile application.

upgraded flutter, dart through CMD

Answer (score 0):

Try to find file in your project that import dart:ffi

```dart
import 'dart:ffi';
```

and delete that import line, here is the relevant error: [Error: Not found: 'dart:ffi' with flutter web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73762786/error-not-found-dartffi-with-flutter-web)

Answer (score 0):

FLUTTER MOBILE:
I had this problem on a Flutter mobile project. Seems it was a PICNIC issue.

My mobile device wasn't plugged into the PC, so Flutter attempted to build for Web. Problem is dart:ffi doesn't work on Web, so you get this error.

Just plugged my device in properly and then picked it as the build destination. Boom, works.

FLUTTER WEB:
While searching for a fix, I found various answers around the web mentioning that people are either importing dart:ffi themselves in the project, or they are using a non-web library which has dart:ffi as a dependency.
Hope this helps :)